# Use AngularJS nested ng-repeat to create elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working with angularjs ng-repeat. I have this code:

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    var items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
    $scope.items = items;
  });
```

I want to have html result like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="">1</a>
    <a href="">2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">3</a>
    <a href="">4</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">5</a>
    <a href="">6</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">7</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The li element needs to be automatically generated as well. I have tried to use ng-repeat, but I am having difficulty with nested ng-repeat.

Comment: Please include your most promising attempt, including the `ng-repeat`.  It's very helpful for us to see what you've tried.  It allows us to better understand the exact problems you're running into.

Comment: you can use `$index` inside of ng-repeat to get the iterator offset. You could probably use that in combination with the mod `%` operator to build that HTML

Comment: While `$index` is an option, I prefer keeping this kind of logic in the angular controller (javascript).  I'd turn the array into an array of pairs first, then `ng-repeat` on that array of pairs.

Comment: @Brian Glaz Thanks. Could you tell me more about creating the offset, I think this is exactly what I want to achieve.

Comment: @ryanyuyu, thanks for tip. I will think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split you array in multiple arrays

```
items = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7]];
```

And this new array you can bind to html

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="li in items"> 
        <a href="" ng-repeat="atags in li">{{atags}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've created you jsfiddle take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/k65wmddL/